# C# UTF7Encoding for first bracket ' { '

Tags: c#, .net

While reading bytes from a file containing UTF7 encoded characters the first bracket '{' is supposed to be  encoded to 123 or 007B but it is not happening.All other characters are encoded right but not '{'.The code I am using is given below.

```
 StreamReader _HistoryLocation = new StreamReader("abc.txt");
 String _ftpInformation = _HistoryLocation.ReadLine();
 UTF7Encoding utf7 = new UTF7Encoding();

 Byte[] encodedBytes = utf7.GetBytes(_ftpInformation);
```

What might be the problem ?

Comment: Try `(new UTF7Encoding()).GetBytes("{")` in LINQPad, for instance.

Comment: From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7): "*UTF-7 allows multiple representations of the same source string. In particular ASCII characters can be represented as part of Unicode blocks.*..." So as long as it is *valid* UTF-7, even if not expected... (much like GZipStream output is *valid*, even not *ideal*)

Comment: When GetChars is used it works perfectly                           `encodedChars = utf7.GetChars(_ftpInformation);`

Comment: @pst as per RFC 2152 [link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2152.txt) the value of '{' in UTF-7 encoding should be 123.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [RFC2152](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2152.txt) that you reference '{' and similar characters may only optionally be encoded as directly - they may instead be encoded.

Notice that `UTF7Encoding` has an [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3y0303z.aspx) with an `allowOptionals` flag that will directly encode the RFC2152 optional characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked                                                `UTF7Encoding utf7 = new UTF7Encoding(true);`